# How to use onRequestPermissionsResult to handle permissions in React Native Android module?

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

I would like to use `onRequestPermissionsResult` in a native Android module, that can be imported into a React Native project.

The permission handling needs to happen in the module - so [PermissionsAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid) or changing the project MainActivity won't work. For the similar `onActivityResult` there is a way to [create and add a listener](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult) to the ReactApplicationContext.

Is there a way to do this for `onRequestPermissionsResult`?

Edit: Added native module code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
public class NativeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public NativeModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        ...
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void requestPermissions() {
        getCurrentActivity().requestPermissions(...)
    }

    // is it possible to hook into the requestPermissions callback with the result from within the module? 
    // public boolean onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) { }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Upload your code so that it can be checked

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not well documented but yes you can.

1. Update your `NativeModule` to also implement [PermissionListener](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.62.0/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/PermissionListener.java) and override the [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.62.0/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/PermissionListener.java#L24) method.
2. Cast the current activity to [PermissionAwareActivity](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.62.0/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/PermissionAwareActivity.java) and call its [requestPermissions()](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.62.0/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/PermissionAwareActivity.java#L28) method passing `this` as the `listener` argument.

Here's an example:

```
public class NativeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements PermissionListener {

    @ReactMethod
    public void requestPermissions() {
        PermissionAwareActivity activity = (PermissionAwareActivity) getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity == null) {
            // Handle null case
        }

        activity.requestPermissions(..., this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        // Handle result
        return true;
    }
}
```